# How do I make multiple cursors in VS Code, one for each attribute of an HTML tag?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, code-editor

Let's say I have something like this

```
<Button color="secondary" className='circular-btn' fullWidth>
```

and I want to use a keyboard shortcut to have a cursor before color, one before className and one before fullWidth.
I know ctrl+alt+arrow will do that when they are already in column. I know I can do an alt+click for each but they could be many, and it's done often.

I believe there's a keyboard shortcut for this because I've seen people do it in videos.
It is mostly to just press enter afterwards and have the attributes in column.

Anyone knows how it's done?

Comment: You should also look at the `HTML > Format: Wrap Attributes` setting if you want them in a column automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to always have them in a column. I want the multiple cursors, so that I choose when to make them into a column.